# Can you update contract token decimals and token name?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

So I'd like to change token decimals and token name in a specific contract. Is it possible?

Comment: Have fudged a specific token contract and really would like to edit those values :(I

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately once a contract is deployed the values cannot be changed. If it were possible to do so, then nobody would trust smart contracts.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't (unless they were programmed to allow such change, which would not comply at all with the ERC20 specifications, and as @Zenos Pavlakou mentioned, being able to modify the decimals would defeat the purpose of smart contracts).

What you could do, which would require quite some work, depending the status of the ICO, is issuing a new token with a new name and decimals and allow your current token holders to exchange them for the new one at the corresponding rate so they keep holding the same value. Not easy at all, but doable if you don't have any other alternatives.

Comment: if you add selfdestruct(owner);   in a function to a contract that made ERC-20 tokens - would it destroy the tokens (if they are still held by the contract) ?